# kotlin creating visibility by using if condition with time

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

i set visibility to an imageview that disappears when clicked and i want it to be invisible when not clicked along 1 second. thanks in advance.   [i dont want to use postdelayed because it doesnt work fine here so i want to do that with if statement]

```
fun hideImages() {

    runnable = Runnable {
        for (image in imageArray) {
            image.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        val random = Random()
        val index = random.nextInt(8 - 0)
        imageArray[index].visibility = View.VISIBLE
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
    }
    handler.post(runnable)
}

fun increaseScore(view: View) {
    score++
    txScore.text = "Score: " + score
    for (image in imageArray){
        image.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    for (image in imageArray) {
        image.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
    val random = Random()
    val index = random.nextInt(8 - 0)
    imageArray[index].visibility = View.VISIBLE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your `hideImages` function immediately posts your runnable without a delay, so the code in it will run immediately. Then it posts itself again with a delay so it will run repeatedly forever every 1000ms. You should only post it once, outside the Runnable, and do that with a delay. And you probably want to postpone when it runs back up to 1000ms each time the button clicks, so you should remove the runnable and re-post it.

```
fun hideImagesAfterDelay() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    runnable = Runnable {
        for (image in imageArray) {
            image.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        val index = Random.nextInt(8 - 0)
        imageArray[index].visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but maybe you want all views to be visible immediately and one of them to disappear later. In that case, you should make them visible synchronously (outside the Runnable):

```
fun hideImagesAfterDelay() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    for (image in imageArray) {
        image.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
    runnable = Runnable {
        val index = Random.nextInt(8 - 0)
        imageArray[index].visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
}
```

Comment: the second part was a problem i have fixed i didnt want to see all views visible . the first part i tried but didnt get the result that i want , what im trying to do is that when i clicked the image the score increases one point, and the imageView appears and disappears in different point of layout, after 2 3 clicks the view moves very fast noway to click it does that every 3 4 clicks, i want to give a view each time one second to disappear when not clicked, like this each 1sec one view disappears and it come up to random view, i want each view has 1sec seperately to disappear when not clicked

Comment: So these different views can all be becoming visible and invisible at different times or at the same time? If so, then you need separate runnables for each view because they each will need their own timer.

Comment: now it does that at different times later i ll get it done at the same time, i ll try seperate runnables and see , sorry i took your time, thank you very much